# Length after decimal point

Tags: decimal

Below code gives error if I enter more than 3 values after decimal. But I want to increase the length after decimal from 2 to 3.

I have increased `precisionValue.length()>2` to `precisionValue.length()>3`. but the error remains same

```
       if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {
        boolean month2 = validator.validateDecimal(str.trim());
        if (!month2) {
            errors.rejectValue(MONTH2, "10005");
        }
        if(str.contains(".")){
            String decValue = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("."));
            String precisionValue = str.substring(str.indexOf(".")+1);
            if(decValue.length()>9) {
                errors.rejectValue(MONTH2, "10035");
            }
            if(precisionValue.length()>2) {
                errors.rejectValue(MONTH2, "10038");
            }
        }
        else if(str.length()>9) {
            errors.rejectValue(MONTH2, "10035");
        }
             }
```

Comment: Mentioning the programming language would be wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that it is in C# and corrected the syntax. You can do in reverse to achieve your programming language. If I choose a number in string format having more than 3 digits after decimal, it should go in  errors.rejectValue(month2, "10038"); line of code and it is working in expected way. I cannot understand your problem completely.

```
            string str = "1.2345";
            if (str != null && str.Length > 0)
            {
                bool month2 = validator.validateDecimal(str.Trim());
                if (!month2)
                {
                    errors.rejectValue(month2, "10005");
                }
                if (str.Contains("."))
                {
                    String decValue = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("."));
                    String precisionValue = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(".") + 1);
                    if (decValue.Length > 9)
                    {
                        errors.rejectValue(month2, "10035");
                    }
                    if (precisionValue.Length > 3)
                    {
                        errors.rejectValue(month2, "10038");
                    }
                }
                else if (str.Length > 9)
                {
                    errors.rejectValue(month2, "10035");
                }
            }
```